# Http Statuscode when waiting for lock-release takes to long?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I am using a lock mechanism to make sure that two parallel calls do not update the same row causing unexpected behavior. So my code is something like this: (no real world example)

```
public class UserController {
  public ActionResult AddReputation(int id, int repAmount) {
    int lockWait=0;
    bool alreadyLocked=true;
    while (alreadyLocked) {
       alreadyLocked=GetLockForUser(id);
       Thread.Wait(1000);
       lockWait++;
       if (lockWait>10) {
          return new HttpStatus(xxx);
       }
   }
   SetlockForUser(id);
   AddUserRep(id,repAmount);
   return new Content("Well Done");
    }
  }
```

So. If after 10 seconds the lock still exists, I want to tell the caller "Please try again later, someone else is just saving data for that user".

What would be the best HTTP-Code in a REST-API for that?
`409 Conflict`? or `423 Locked`?

*Note: This is no SQL-DB. I got no real transaction-mechanisms I can use. So I have to implement my own locking mechanism.*

Comment: A saner way to solve this is to use etags and If-Match.

Comment: @Evert The server would still have to obtain a lock before it can safely evaluate the `If-Match`. So it could still time out. But I agree that PUT + `If-Match` may be a good idea for something called “AddReputation”.

Comment: A bit OT, but: I think `while(!GetLockForUser(id)) {` makes for cleaner (and safer) code. Also: Do locks expire after some time? I see no release mechanism. Is `GetLockForUser(id)` blocking? I also feel 1,000ms is too much for a delay.

Comment: @DaSourcerer that was just a quick example. No real-world code

Comment: Well, it caught my eye ヽ（´ー｀）┌

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ask yourself: what would the *client* want to do in this situation?

From your description, it sounds like the client’s only choice is to wait and try again later. So [503 (Service Unavailable)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4) seems like a good fit:

> indicates that the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some delay

Also, the generic [500 (Internal Server Error)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) is always at your service.

423 (Locked) may or may not be a good fit. It was designed as part of [WebDAV’s locking mechanisms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-6), where clients explicitly lock and unlock resources. Generally, clients are more likely to understand a 503 error (very common in the wild) than a 423 error (uncommon outside of WebDAV): 423 is likely to be treated as a generic [client error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5), which may not be helpful. That said, [the definition of 423 itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.3) does not require that WebDAV locking be involved. If you want to distinguish this situation from something like a server downtime (which would result in a 503), then 423 may work.

[409 (Conflict)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) does **not** seem like a good fit:

> This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the 423 as it is pretty much tied into WebDAV's locking mechanism: IMHO it is not so much meant to be used by generic locking implementations. But 503 is indeed a perfect match.